# A database about transactions?

Tags: data-request

I wish to have a database about some products that their transactions are recorded. So, ideally it has at least the following columns:

- Transaction ID
- Customer ID
- Date
- Product

Any guidance about how I can find this database would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the open database that I was looking for:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/acquire-valued-shoppers-challenge/data

> **Acquire Valued Shoppers Challenge**
>   Predict which shoppers will become repeat buyers